# How can i init my presolver in python version of SCIP

Tags: scip

I am doing a SCIP problem in python version. It takes more than a hour to solve my problem. So I want to give the model an initialization. I find there is presol in pyscipopt, but I really don't know how to use it.

Can presol provide what I want? If it can, do I need to init all variables or I can just init some of the variables? Can I get a little exam about how to use presol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Presolving" refers to reformulating/reducing the model to make it easier to solve. I suppose that you just want to set an initial solution to kick-start SCIP. This usually helps but your mileage may vary depending on the specific problem you're trying to solve.

To add a solution, proceed like this:

```
sol = model.createSol()
vars = model.getVars()

model.setSolVal(sol, vars[0], 5.0)
model.setSolVal(sol, vars[1], 0.0)

accepted = model.addSol(sol)
```

Comment: The 'self' argument in line 1 (createSol) comes from the fact that you copied this snippet from inside a heuristic. It should be removed, if possible, or made clearer.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want. After I set my sol by using model.createSol, model.setSolVal and model.addSol, I use model.optimize() to solve the problem. But it still takes a long time to solve the problem. Do I need to make other config to make sure that the solution is set, or just the problem is too big to solve it quickly?

Comment: Apparently, the model is not too easy. One thing you can and should always do when solving similar problems many times is parameter tuning. Have a look into the statistics (`model.printStatistics()`) to see for example which heuristics or presolvers took too much time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think i see what you mean. I am not good at optimization method, but I will try my best to understand what happend when my model is optimized. Thank you.